# Global error handling in ReactJS App does not work well with IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

My React application seems to have some issues with IE 11 as it only loads blank white page. We tried using polyfill but it still does not work.

Plus, we are logging all runtime errors using window.onerror method. This works for all runtime errors that occur in the app. We were expecting that when the IE-React error occurred, it would also be logged using window.onerror, but it didn't. Following is the code snippet that I am using -

```
<script>
    window.onerror = function(message, url, lineno, colno, error) {
        $.post({
            url: '/frontEndExceptionHandler',
            contentType: 'text/plain',
            data: 'Source:' + url + ':' + lineno + ' Error:' + message + ' UserAgent:' + navigator.userAgent,
        })
    }
</script>
```

Could anyone please guide me on what could be the issue, and how can I log what the error is?

Comment: Have you opened the dev tools in IE to see what the problem is?

Comment: @Ray, my question is, whatever the problem there may be, why it was not caught in global error handling, i.e. `window.onerror`? On devtools, it does show the error and there would be the measures to fix it. I want to log the this error using post call that I am making. Thanks!

Comment: My guess is that it blew up before your handler was registered.

Comment: Thanks Ray, could you suggest any approaches on how can I handle it, or fixing the React-IE problem is the only solution?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing what the error is, but in my experience these kinds of issues (blank screen, error handler not firing) are caused by syntax that IE doesn't understand--JSX or new language features that haven't been polyfilled--and can be resolved by tweaking the webpack or babel config. So the first step is identifying the error. What's blowing up and why?